# How to fix 'SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED' error only thrown in Pycharm (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, ssl-certificate

When making an https request in Pycharm using a Python3 interpreter I receive the error:

`ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)`

I'm inclined to assume this is a problem with my Pycharm configuration as this problem only occurs in Pycharm when using any version of Python3. The code runs fine in Pycharm using Python2.7 and it works fine running Python3 in commandline.

Through Pycharm I have tried creating new virtual environments using different versions of Python3. All of which based on interpreters that can successfully run the code independent of Pycharm.

The most common solution to this error is to run `Install Certificates.command` found at `/Applications/Python 3.x/` but running this only confirms that the `certifi` package is already up-to-date.

The last line of the code below throws the error:

```
headers = {"authuser":username, "authpass":password}
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(url)
conn.request("POST",requestpath, headers)
```

Comment: Bumped into the same problem after 5 years with PyCharm v2022.3.1. It is a totally PyCharm-specific problem, because of the pydevd.py script it actually invokes. 

This fails:
`python "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --client 127.0.0.1 --port 62277 --file my_script.py`

This works:
`python my_script.py`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're running Python 3.4.3 or later, and if you're okay with not verifying your target, you could try disabling certificate and hostname checks:

```
headers = {"authuser":user, "authpass":pass}
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(url, context=ssl._create_unverified_context())
conn.request("POST",requestpath, headers)
```

From the official Python3 documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html:

> Changed in version 3.4.3: This class now performs all the necessary
>   certificate and hostname checks by default. To revert to the previous,
>   unverified, behavior ssl._create_unverified_context() can be passed to
>   the context parameter.